# foreach loop quits before execute last array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to make a foreach loop by removing the elements in the for loop. But foreach loop finish before executes all array. I mean last loop is [ 6, 7, 6 ] and i expect to run for one more loop but it quits. I can do it using for loop or an other way but really i confused on why it quits before execute last array. Thanks for any help.

(The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired.)

```
function example() {
let A = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6];
  A.forEach(element => {
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if (i === 0) continue;

      if (A[i] === element) {
        A.splice(i, 1);
        A.shift();
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(A);
  });

  return A[0];
}
```

output:

```
[ 3, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 7, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 6, 7, 6 ]
6


expected:

[ 3, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 7, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
[ 6, 7, 6 ]
[7]
7
```

Comment: What exactly is the code supposed to do? Remove two identical numbers, one of which is at the first index? Shouldn’t the `for` loop start with `let i = 1`, then? Mutating an array inside an iteration method such as `forEach` is a _bad_ idea.

Comment: use A.slice().forEach

Comment: The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired. I was actually using two nested foreach loops but then i changed to use "continue".. @SebastianSimon

Comment: Yes I can use slice but still i don't know the reason why foreach loop quits before execute last array :) @abhirathore2006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of using `shift`. I think you wanted to know why this is happening, not how to solve it, right? You may find solutions based on your requirements, but read before you solve it using chunk of code.

You can read the official doc of MDN web docs how `shift()`, `Array.forEach()` works.

[`MDN web Docs :: forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited. If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using shift()) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped

it quits before the last iteration, this is because, after first three iteration, when you use shift, it will try to shift to the next index, but at that certain point there will be only 3 elements left, as already forEach next index is 3/4, for this iteration, forEach stops as index will be greater then the length of the remaining items.

You can check the following code and some console logs:

```
function example() {
let A = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6];
A.forEach((element, index) => {

    // if you look carefully
    // last index for this array will be 3
    // means, it has already visited 4 items
    // so, after shifting one more location
    // it will stop

    console.log(index);

    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) continue;

        if (A[i] === element) {
            A.splice(i, 1);
            A.shift();
            break;
        }
    }

    // this console log will tell you
    // that it has 3 items left in
    // this container

    console.log(A);
  });

return A[0];
}

console.log(example())
```

Output:

```
Current Index:  0
[ 3, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
Current Index:  1
[ 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
Current Index:  2
[ 7, 7, 6, 7, 6 ]
Current Index:  3 // look here, it means forEach() already visited 4 items
[ 6, 7, 6 ]
Final:  6
```

So, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is not best solution, but it should work for your required criteria.

```
function example()
{
 let A = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6];

 for (let j = 0; j < A.length-1 ; j++)
 {
    for (let i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {

      if (A[i] === A[j])
     {
        j = j -1;
        A.splice(i, 1);
        A.shift();
        break;
      }

    }

    console.log(A);
  }

  return A[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function example() {
    let A = [9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 7, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6];
      A.forEach((element,index,array) => {
       
         console.log("before removal: "+A.length+" ["+ A+"]"+"element: "+element +"index: "+index)
  
    //splice("which index","howmany","toadd")
          if (A[index] === element) {
           A.splice(index, 1,"");
             console.log("after removal: "+A.length+" ["+ A+"]")
            
          }
          console.log(A);
        }
      
      );
     
    
    }

    example();
```

> In this code I
>   have just removed the (iterating) index and have inserted empty value
>   in that place so that the size of the array cannot be disturbed. In
>   your code the error was the array index , index was been updated but
>   the elements of array was shifted one index further, so for index=1(
>   the array got updated after .shift and has 2 at index 0 which would
>   never be visited in iteration again).

please go through the output patiently, I have consoled the array to show you exactly how the elements are being removed from the array.
I dont know why you want to show 7 and of which index. So please make your question a little more clear